# Can't get monitor image back on after toggling monitor power button

Tags: 14.04, xorg, video

When I toggle monitor power off and on again - it doesn't come back to desktop. I see blank screen instead. Interestingly - if I type `Ctrl + Alt +F1` - I can get into terminal and then I can get back into desktop by typing:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Suspend works normally  (monitor wakes up just fine). Any ideas?

P.S.
Xubuntu 14.04 with the most latest updates on Gigabyte Brix 2 Pro

P.S.
[here's bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-settings/+bug/1313539)